# Game Center leaderboard not dismissing

Tags: ios, xcode, game-center

I was implementing Game Center into my app and all was going well except for the leaderboard done button not dismissing the leaderboard even with gameCenterControllerDidFinish added in. I call up the leaderboard with the touch of a button in the .m file as so:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];



     if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"rankButton"]) {

        [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"fishtran.m4a" waitForCompletion: NO]];
         GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] 
    init];
            if (gameCenterController != nil)
       {

            gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateAchievements;
            UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
            [vc presentViewController: gameCenterController animated: YES completion:nil];
        }
    } else if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"Leaderboard"]) {
        GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc]  
init];
        if (gameCenterController != nil)
        {

            gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
            UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
            [vc presentViewController: gameCenterController animated: YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
 ...
```

and then I added thegameCenterControllerDidFinish immediately after as so:

```
- (void)gameCenterControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController*)gameCenterController {

    UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
    [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

and the done button still doesn't work and i haven't been able to find any solutions. And yes, I do have GKGameCenterControllerDelegate in my .h file. Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!